# Iterate over Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am creating a Dictionary and add string as key and another Dictionary as values which refer to a particular user.
I am not able to iterate over the key (string in dictionary), and if that matches my requirement, i need to get the values in that dictionary.

Something like :

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> 
mydictionary.Add(string,Dictionary<string,string>)
```

here is what i want to do :

```
foreach(string s in Dictionary<string,Dictionary>) 
{    if(s.contains("Foo"))    {
        return the dictionary which is mapped to this key.
}
}
```

Comment: Use `foreach(string s in mydictionary.Keys)`

Comment: Are you sure using a dictionary is the best approach? If you are just going to iterate over it then there are probably better options? Depends where / how else you are using it of course!

Comment: You want to check for `s.ContainsKey("foo")` and also this looks pretty bad why not use class with properties.

Comment: @CoderofCode: Or use `ContainsKey`.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to iterate over the keys when you can do `dictionary.ContainsKey(key)` to check if exists and then `dictionary[key]` to get it?

Comment: @Pinx0 I suspect it's because OP is looking for ***substrings*** within the keys.

Comment: If he is looking for substrings he's not looking for one particular dictionary but for anyone that matches his substring, so the method should return a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @Pinx0 Not if OP only wants to return the first one found. An assumption that there's an extra specification here might not be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
foreach (var s in myDictionary.Keys)
{
    if (s.Contains("Foo"))
        return myDictionary[s];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Linq one-liner that should do what you need...

```
return myDictionary
    .Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Contains("Foo"))
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @CoderofCode Because that's not what the OP wants to do. They are looking for ***substrings*** within the keys. There might be trie-like structures that would be more efficient for this, but that would be beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Yes I got that after looking at the question one more time. That's why removed the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to return the inner dictionary (the value), you should use `TryGetValue`, which is best performance-wise:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue("Foo", out values) && values != null)
{
    // do something with the value
}
```

If that doesn't suit your needs, you could iterate over the keys, or over the key-value-pairs, depending on your needs:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> kvp in dictionary)
{
    if(kvp.Key.Contains("Foo"))
    {
        var dictionary = kvp.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

            Dictionary<String, string> di = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            di.Add("1", "Hello1");
            myDictionary.Add("Item1", di);

            di.Add("2", "Hello2");
            myDictionary.Add("Item2", di);

            di.Add("3", "Hello3");
            myDictionary.Add("Item3", di);


            var result = myDictionary.Where(c => c.Key == "Item1").FirstOrDefault();
            if (result.Key != null)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> output = result.Value;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this way.

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry Item in myDictionary){
  Console.WrileLine("Name : "+ Item.Key+" Value"+Item.value.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I have picked one of the solutions provided which suited my requirement.